# Attach SAN storage share path to Two linux machine

Tags: linux, centos, storage

I have two VM running on Centos7. One is active and another one is passive server.

And created 200GB size LUN in SAN for common share path for both VMs. If I upload files on one server, then same can be seen on another one. Even it helps on failover case of single VM.

Can someone please share me how to setup this method ?.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use NFS Server so that your can freely share directories plus when one of your nfs client went down you can easily start another then share your files again.